# Recursive function to display given binary tree

Tags: python

I have been struggling to see how to progress with writing a recursive function for this question in Python

So given a binary tree define with a class and attribute in Python class script.

for example given a binary tree below:

define with class function with node.left_node and node.right_node in class

```
                          6
       0                                    7
                 3                                    8
            2         5                                        9
         1         4
```

Hence in this case we have

1. tree.value = 6
2. tree.left_node.value = 0
3. tree.left_node.right_node.value = 3
4. tree.left_node.right_node.left_node.left_node.value = 1
5. etc

I hope you can see the binary tree above:

I want to print it with a recursive function print it growing up as  below

________1___4

_________2___5_______________9

___________3_______________8

_______0_______________7

_______________6

with the underscore used for positioning them in the correct location for binary tree.

not sure if I should, as its all wrong, below is what I did.

```html
def print_growing_up(tree):
    tree_height = tree.height()
    total_length = 2 ** ( tree_height + 1 ) - 1           
    _print_tree(tree, 0, tree_height, int((total_length-1)/2))

def _print_tree(node, level, height, spaces):
    if level > height:
        return
    if node.value is None:
        return
    else:
        _print_tree(node.left_node, level + 1, height, int((spaces-1)/2 ))
        _print_tree(node.right_node, level + 1, height, int(((spaces+1)/2)+spaces))
        print(spaces)
        print('_' * spaces + str(node.value))
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is called post order tree traversal, first traverse left child, then right child and then the root.

```
def print_post_order(root): 

#If the root exists on the tree
    if root: 
        print_post_order(root.left) 
        print_post_order(root.right) 
        print(root.val)
```